# Writing a helper class that queries the database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Java & Spring Boot. I have written a "helper" class which I put reusable functions inside of relating to `Users`. One of the functions queries the database and returns a single `user`. Since this is my first time using Spring Boot I am unsure if I am doing it correctly. If I am not supposed to have a reusable helper function that queries the database in a helper class like this where should I put functions like these which will be reused throughout the backend? Thanks in advance

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@Transactional
public class WGService {

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private UserHelpers userHelpers;

    public Long sendReminderEmail(WGIO.Reminders.emailReminder request) {
        // other code
        User rep = userHelpers.findRepByChildId(request.getMgrId());
    }
}
```

this is the helper class

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@Lazy
public class UserHelpers {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public User findRepByChildId(long mgrId) {
        final User[] rep = {null};
        Optional<List<User>> reps = userRepository.findSpecificParent(mgrId, RoleEnums.Role.ROLE_REP.toString());
        reps.ifPresent(r->{
           rep[0] = r.get(0);
        });
        return rep[0];
    }
}
```

User Repository

```
@Repository
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT u.* FROM users u WHERE u.user_lineage @> (SELECT user_lineage FROM users WHERE id = (SELECT parent_id FROM users WHERE id = CAST(?1 as BIGINT))) AND u.role=?2", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<List<User>> findSpecificParent(Long childId, String role);
}
```

Comment: What you are calling UserHelper is actually UserService. Other than that everything is as per expected convention.

Comment: Why an optional list? A list is empty if there are no results, so an optional list generally makes no sense. Not to mention the, imho, wrong use of optional here.